# Creating a JavaScript Object from JSON File

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have a json file like this below:

**data.json:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "key": "key0",
    "value": "val0"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "key": "key1",
    "value": "val1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "key": "key2",
    "value": "val2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "key": "key3",
    "value": "val3"
  }
]
```

Now, i want to turn this json into javascript object like this format:

**JavaScript Object:**

```
{
  key0: val0,
  key1: val1,
  key2: val2,
  key3: val3
}
```

I have tried to find a solution with the functions (like each, map, ...), but i couldn't find a solution. I am not just looking for a solution, but the most efficent one.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: JSON.parse() and Object.assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` is a good option here, as were reducing from an array to an object.

```js
var json = `[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "key": "key0",
    "value": "val0"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "key": "key1",
    "value": "val1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "key": "key2",
    "value": "val2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "key": "key3",
    "value": "val3"
  }
]`;

var obj = JSON.parse(json).reduce((a,v) => { a[v.key] = v.value; return a; }, {});
console.log(obj);
```